# How to Error handling in VB

Tags: vb.net

How can I make a Exception handling piece of code for to ensure numeric entry? I am doing my final for my visual basic class and there are some errors I would like to make my program perfect :).  Sorry for the title they are really hard to make. I want it so the program doesnt close when someone types a string instead of a integer.

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim year, age, again As Integer
retry:
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The year you were born in!")
    Console.WriteLine("")
    year = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("")
    If year < 1894 Or year > 2014 Then GoTo Toyoung

    age = 2014 - year
    Console.WriteLine("You are " & age & " years old")
    Console.WriteLine("")
```

Comment: vbscript <> vb.net <> vba

Comment: vb.net, Sorry about the title.

Comment: Please post your code, and we might be able to help with it.

Comment: Integer.Parse() - http://www.dotnetperls.com/integer-parse-vbnet

Comment: You're talking about input validation, not error handling.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for fixing that to I just noticed it pasted a wierd way. Thats how it is in my script currently.

Comment: Did your teacher tell you to use GoTo? It gives me the shivers.

Comment: No It just seemed like an easier thing to do. We didn't even learn goto in the class.

Comment: You should be using a loop instead of a goto/label.

Comment: That goto is there for something farther down in the code because this is only 17 lines of the code the whole thing is 120 lines and farther into the code it uses that goto.

Comment: @user3439015: You must **unlearn** what you have learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to input a string, and check to make sure it's numeric with `isnumeric`, like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim year, age, again As Integer
    Dim s as string
retry:
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The year you were born in!")
    Console.WriteLine("")
    s = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("")
    if not isnumeric(s) then goto retry
    year = s
    If year < 1894 Or year > 2014 Then GoTo Toyoung

    age = 2014 - year
    Console.WriteLine("You are " & age & " years old")
    Console.WriteLine("")
```

An alternative method is to use a `Try, Catch` block. It is preferred by some people.

Comment: Except here is where we disagree. Try/Catch really should not be used for input validation...

Comment: After thinking about it, I believe you are correct. Error trapping is expensive and is better used for abnormal situations.

Answer (score 3):

Normally exception handling in VB.NET works this way.

With the start of each process you do this

```
TRY
''Put some code here

CATCH
''Put code on what to do if it throws an error

FINALLY
''Optional: Any thing that has to be done regardless of wether it throws 
''an exception or not. Usually here is where you would close the connection

END TRY
```

In your case you just need to `Validate` the user input. What you will need to do is to check to see if `isnumber(nameoftextbox) = False` then give the user a message and exit the subroutine.

Comment: Well thank you Logixologist I wasn't really sure how to do exception handling and this really helped. I would give you a thumbs up but i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Remember to use `Try/Catch` not for validation of input but rather to catch anything out of the ordinary that may fail.

Comment: You can always go back and do it after you increase your reputation ;)